# Access, Aggregate sums for each day of the week on a monthly basis

Tags: ms-access-2010, aggregate-functions, weekday

I am trying to sum sales totals for each day of the week on a monthly basis.  I believe the Weekday function in Access could be used to do this. The Weekday function code in the query below doesn't work.  How should the Weekday function syntax be revised in order to sum sales totals each day of the week? (The query below has been updated with the correct code and will return the correct results.)

```
SELECT Format(DatePart("m",months.month_start),"00") & "/" & Year(months.month_start) AS [Month/Year], 

(SELECT  Round(Nz(Sum(sales_receipt.SELLING_PRICE*sales_receipt.quantity),0),2)
FROM SALES_RECEIPT
WHERE SALES_RECEIPT.SALE_DATE between months.month_start and months.month_end and weekday(sale_date) = 1) AS [Sunday Sales Total], 

(SELECT  Round(Nz(Sum(sales_receipt.SELLING_PRICE*sales_receipt.quantity),0),2)
FROM SALES_RECEIPT
WHERE SALES_RECEIPT.SALE_DATE between months.month_start and months.month_end and weekday(sale_date) = 2) AS [Monday Sales Total], 

(SELECT  Round(Nz(Sum(sales_receipt.SELLING_PRICE*sales_receipt.quantity),0),2)
FROM SALES_RECEIPT
WHERE SALES_RECEIPT.SALE_DATE between months.month_start and months.month_end and weekday(sale_date) = 3) AS [Tuesday Sales Total], 

(SELECT  Round(Nz(Sum(sales_receipt.SELLING_PRICE*sales_receipt.quantity),0),2)
FROM SALES_RECEIPT
WHERE SALES_RECEIPT.SALE_DATE between months.month_start and months.month_end and weekday(sale_date) = 4) AS [Wednesday Sales Total], 

(SELECT  Round(Nz(Sum(sales_receipt.SELLING_PRICE*sales_receipt.quantity),0),2)
FROM SALES_RECEIPT
WHERE SALES_RECEIPT.SALE_DATE between months.month_start and months.month_end and weekday(sale_date) = 5) AS [Thursday Sales Total], 

(SELECT  Round(Nz(Sum(sales_receipt.SELLING_PRICE*sales_receipt.quantity),0),2)
FROM SALES_RECEIPT
WHERE SALES_RECEIPT.SALE_DATE between months.month_start and months.month_end and weekday(sale_date) = 6) AS [Friday Sales Total], 

(SELECT  Round(Nz(Sum(sales_receipt.SELLING_PRICE*sales_receipt.quantity),0),2)
FROM SALES_RECEIPT
WHERE SALES_RECEIPT.SALE_DATE between months.month_start and months.month_end and weekday(sale_date) = 7) AS [Saturday Sales Total]

FROM (SELECT DateSerial(Year(sale_date), Month(sale_date), 1) AS month_start, 
DateAdd("d", -1,  DateSerial(Year(sale_date), Month(sale_date) + 1, 1)) AS month_end
FROM SALES_RECEIPT 
WHERE sale_date between #1/1# And #12/31#
GROUP BY Year(sale_date), Month(sale_date)) AS months;
```

Comment: Explain symptoms of "it doesn't work". Sample data set of what you would like it to look like, and what it actually comes out as

Comment: When the query is run, an "ENTER PARAMETER VALUE" box appears asking for the "date_value".   If I enter a date_value of 1 which is Sunday, each day of the week for the month of January has the value of $2016.62 ($2016.62 is the sales total for all 31 days in month of January).  Sunday should be $0 because the store is closed on Sunday.  Other than Sunday, each day should have less than $2016.62 but the sum of the totals for each day of the week should add up to $2016.62 for the month of January.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you're not doing an actual comparison of your parameter using the weekday function:

**For each of the weekday comparisons, try changing**

```
weekday(date_value = #))
```

**to this**

> **EDIT-change to remove popup and use actual field**

```
weekday(sale_date) = #)
```

Comment: I made the change  but an "ENTER PARAMETER VALUE" box still appears asking for the "date_value". If I enter a date_value of 1 which is Sunday, there are values only Sunday and the rest of the days are $0.  The value for Sunday for the month of January is $2016.62 ($2016.62 is the sales total for all 31 days in month of January).  If I enter a 2, only Monday has values and the other days are $0.  Monday for the month of January has a value of $2016.62.  It's the same for any day of the week, it provides the monthly total and the other days are $0.

Comment: You've set it up as a parameter - do it will always popup - are you saying you don't want datevalue popping up?

Comment: Updated answer using sales_date field

Comment: Assuming sale_date is a date field not text?

Comment: I didn't want a popup parameter box and sale_date is a date field.  With the updated code  "weekday(sale_date) = 1) AS [Sunday Sales Total]" updated for each day of the week, the query returns the correct results.  Thank you!

Comment: Excellent - make sure to remember to mark this as the answer. Good coding ahead for you!